# MAC VBA Trying to cut one cell from each worksheet and paste in another sheet in next empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to go through each worksheet in the active workbook in which the sheets are created as part of a macro that is working.  The names can be different each time, so I can't just do a lookup.  I want to take one piece of information (same cell on each worksheet) and paste it into the next empty cell in a column on another sheet.

At line 6 I get the error subscript out of range error 9.  I've checked the naming of the sheet I am pasting to and it is correct.  No extra spaces.

It's driving me nuts.  Can you help?

ps I am working on this to run on a MAC which I normally don't do, so maybe I have the code slightly wrong.

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
DoEvents

    sh.Activate
    Range("K5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Payment Ref").Range("b2").Select
    If Range("b2") = "" Then
    Range("b2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Range("b2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
     Else
    Range("b2").Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Range("b2").Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If


Next sh
```

At the end of the run the Payment Ref Spreadsheet should have a column filled with invoice numbers from the invoice sheets created in the previous macro section.  This works perfectly.

Comment: First of all you might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • Then please tell which one is line 6 (everyone counts different). Please tell which code throws the error.

Comment: Sheets("Payment Ref").Range("b2").Select

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` (see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)) and reference a worksheet for all your ranges (eg using `With`).

Also you need to find the last used cell everytime you paste. A good way to find the last used cell in a column is:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp) 'last used cell in column B
```

So the following should work for you

```
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Payment Ref")

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets    
    sh.Range("K5").Copy

    With wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
Next sh
```

Comment: HI.  Now I get a compile error Data Member not found.  I am working on MAC so as I said the coding may be slightly different.  The error is on this line sh.Range("K5").Copy asnd range is highlighted so guessing on MAC it has to be worded differently.  I know this works on PC but coding for working on MAC it doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using `.Select` in general, as linked in the comments. This is most likely the cause for your error. Also, if you perform this code on more than 1 or 2 worksheets (depending on if `B2` already has a value) the procedure will keep putting the values in cell `B3`. I'd suggest the following changes:

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Range("K5").Copy
    Sheets("Payment Ref").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("Payment Ref").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next sh
```

I think this should work just as well:

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Range("K5").Copy Sheets("Payment Ref").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next sh
```

Comment: Feel free to downvote, but please also let me know your suggestions on improving my answer, no way to learn otherwise.

Comment: Not my dv, but are you sure you wanted to paste on `sh`? Doesn't look like that's what OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks all.  I'll try suggestions and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for the .select tip

Comment: Hi.  Also tried this and I get an error on this line: sh.Range("K5").Copy Sheets("Payment Ref").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) .  with Range highlighted - compile error data member not found.  As I said I am working on MAC so maybe the code is slightly different.